# PHP: One of the values as key in array

Tags: php, arrays, key, key-value

I have an array like this:

```
$arrayIn = [
     [ 0 => "3",
       1 => "12345"
     ],
     [ 0 => "2",
       1 => "123"
     ]
];
```

and want to get an array like this:

```
$arrayOut = [
     12345 => "3",
     123 => "2"   
];
```

I tried with `array_values` and `array_combine` but can't get this result. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) for this

```
$arrayOut = array_column($arrayIn, 0, 1);
```

The second argument specifies which column to select and the third one specifies which column to use as keys.

Keep in mind that if you have duplicate values in column 1, they will be overwritten in the result because array keys must be unique by definition, but that caveat applies to any solution to this problem.

Comment: This is so succinct. +1

Comment: Thanks, @ishegg. Gotta love array_column.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through your original array and build a new one with the second value as key and the first as value:

```
$arrayOut = [];
foreach ($arrayIn as $arr) {
    $arrayOut[$arr[1]] = $arr[0];
}
var_dump($arrayOut);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/u3fCC)

*Result*

> array (size=2)
>    12345 => string '3' (length=1)
>    123 => string '2' (length=1)